# Insert Datetimepicker text in SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql

how to Insert Datetimepicker text in SQL Database as datetime datatype

Comment: What is the problem - getting DateTime form DateTimePicker or inserting DateTime into the database?

Answer (score 2):

In order to parse the datetime from datetime picker you can do the following:

```
string dt = dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

And then in order to insert it in your database you can do:

```
Insert into table (id, mytime) 
values("5",  CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT( varchar(11), dt, 101))
```

If you need information on how to access your database you can read the following [article in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the text in C#, and insert the parsed `DateTime`. Example:

```
var date = new DateTime(dateTimePickerText);
InsertIntoSqlDatabase(date); // Code for inserting here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert date as `DateTime` directly (without converting into string) by using `DataRow`.
For example:

```
  using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            sqlconn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = #your_serwer\instance#; Initial Catalog = #db_name#; User Id = #user#; Password = #pwd#;";
            sqlconn.Open();

            // select your date and a key index field on a table (e.g. "id")
            string sql = "select id, some_date from table_1 where id = 1 ";

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlconn))
            {
                using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
                {
                    adapter.Fill(table);                       

                    DataRow r = null;
                    if (table.Rows.Count == 1)
                        r = table.Rows[0];   // case, when there is an row for update
                    else
                        r = table.NewRow();  // case, when there is no row, and you would like to insert one

                    r.BeginEdit();
                    // here you assign your value
                    r["some_date"] = dateTimePicker.Value;
                    r.EndEdit();

                    if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        // in case of insert, provide here some other values for other non null columns like
                        r["id"] = 2;
                        // also you have to add this row into DataTable
                        table.Rows.Add(r);
                    }

                    // this will update the database
                    SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                    adapter.Update(table);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope, this helps.